# How to add new column in pandas dataframe with two conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add a new column on the basis of a condition in pandas dataframe

## input file

```
Name    C2Mean  C1Mean
a       2        0
b       4        2
c       6        2.5
```

These are the conditions:

```
if C1Mean = 0; log2FC = log2([C2Mean=2])
if C1Mean > 0; log2FC = log2([C2Mean=4]/[C1Mean=2])
if C1Mean > 0; log2FC = log2([C2Mean=4]/[C1Mean=2])
```

Based on these conditions I want to add a new column 'log2FC' like this:

```
Name    C2Mean  C1Mean  log2FC
a        2        0     1
b        4        2     1
c        6        2.5   1.2630344058
```

The code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
    
def induced_genes(rsem_exp_data):
    pwd = os.getcwd()
    data = pd.read_csv(rsem_exp_data,header=0,sep="\t")
    data['log2FC'] = [np.log2(data['C2Mean']/data['C1Mean'])\
    if data['C2Mean'] > 0] else np.log2(data['C2Mean'])]
    print(data.head(5))

induced_genes('induced.genes')
```

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: It looks to me you have only one condition.

Comment: @barbsan I am getting error at the below line of the code

data['log2FC'] = [np.log2(data['C2Mean']/data['C1Mean']) if data['C2Mean'] > 0] else np.log2(data['C2Mean'])]

Comment: @rpanai
Two lines are showing same condition. 

data['log2FC'] = [np.log2(data['C2Mean']/data['C1Mean']) if data['C2Mean'] > 0] else np.log2(data['C2Mean'])]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work and it's faster than apply

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["a", "b", "c"], "C2Mean":[2,4,6], "C1Mean":[0, 2, 2.5]})

df["log2FC"] = np.where(df["C1Mean"]==0,
                        np.log2(df["C2Mean"]), 
                        np.log2(df["C2Mean"]/df["C1Mean"]))
```

**UPDATE: Timing**

```py
N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({"C2Mean":np.random.randint(0,10,N), 
                   "C1Mean":np.random.randint(0,10,N)})

%%timeit -n10
a = np.where(df["C1Mean"]==0,
             np.log2(df["C2Mean"]),
             np.log2(df["C2Mean"]/df["C1Mean"]))

1.06 ms ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n10
b = df.apply(lambda x: np.log2(x["C2Mean"]/x["C1Mean"]) if x["C1Mean"]> 0 
                       else np.log2(x["C2Mean"]), axis=1)

248 ms ± 5.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The speed up is ~233x.

***UPDATE 2: Remove RuntimeWarning**

Just add this at the beginning

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is running properly. I am getting the warning when I am running with orinional file.  
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2
  np.log2(data["C1Mean"]/data["C2Mean"]))

Comment: This is due because by default it tries to calculate even the case when `df["C1Mean"]==0`. You can ignore it with the code I added

Comment: Could you please explain why is not running properly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["a", "b", "c"], "C2Mean":[2,4,6], "C1Mean":[0, 2, 2.5]})

df.head()

Name    C2Mean  C1Mean
a         2     0.0
b         4     2.0
c         6     2.5

df["log2FC"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.log2(x["C2Mean"]/x["C1Mean"]) if x["C1Mean"]> 0 else np.log2(x["C2Mean"]), axis=1)

df.head()

Name    C2Mean  C1Mean  log2FC
a        2      0.0     1.000000
b        4      2.0     1.000000
c        6      2.5     1.263034
```

Here `axis=1` implies that you want to do this operation for all the rows.

Comment: Thank you for help. The code is running properly. But below warning appears when I am running it on the real file

RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2
  df["log2FC"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.log2(x["C1Mean"]/x["C2Mean"]) if x["C2Mean"]> 0 else np.log2(x["C1Mean"]), axis=1)

Comment: This is a correct solution but you don't want to use it with a big `df`.